# Which statistics test should I use?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data

Group High is a year in which there was a high temperature change and group Low is a year in which there was a low temperature change. The classes represent an the percentage of coverage for a species on a plate. E.g. class 0 = 0% growth, class 4 = 50-75% growth, class 6 = >75% growth.  (I will not compare an amount of temperature change to an amount of growth)

I need to know if there is a significant difference between group High and group Low. Which statistical test can I use?

Both of my variables are categorical, right?

I use R studio and Excel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A chi-square test.

Comment: Even so, the assumptions of a chi-squared test are violated with such a small dataset no?

Comment: Perhaps an exact test would be more appropriate than a $\chi^2$ test in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

A suggestion has been made to do a chi-squared
test on your $2 \times 6$ table of counts to see if the distributions for High and Low are
different. That is one reasonable possibility  among several.

```
H = c(6, 4,14, 3, 3, 2)
L = c(0, 3,15,10, 6, 1)
TBL = rbind(H,L);  TBL

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
H    6    4   14    3    3    2
L    0    3   15   10    6    1

chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 11.168, df = 5, p-value = 0.04815

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

It has also been commented that the counts in some
of the cells are too sparse for a reliable P-value. Hence
the 'Warning'. (Some of the expected counts are less than 5.)

```
chisq.test(TBL)$exp
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
H 2.865672 3.343284 13.85075 6.208955 4.298507 1.432836
L 3.134328 3.656716 15.14925 6.791045 4.701493 1.567164
Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

You could try combining Classes 0 & 1 and Classes 4 & 5 to get a $2 \times 4$ table of counts and then do a chi-squared test on that table.

Alternatively, as implemented in R, it is possible to obtain a
more useful P-value by simulation, which is marginally
significant at the 5% level.

```
chisq.test(TBL, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TBL
X-squared = 11.168, df = NA, p-value = 0.04698
```

Moreover, as you suggest, your six 'Classes' are ordinal. So, you might want to consider looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel%20test%20%28CMH%29%20is%20a,control%20status%20while%20taking%20into%20account%20the%20stratification.). Also, you might look at the
links in the margin of this page noted as 'Related'.
Your strategy should be to select the *one* test that you think
best matches the nature of your data and your objectives. (You should ***not*** try all
possible tests and pick the one with the smallest P-value.)